# how to use php variable in document header?

Tags: php

i am trying to change download image name inside php header but it never works:
I tried all these possibilities but non of them work. could any one tell me what i am doing wrong ?

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$imageNewName");
```

**php that download image:**

```
<?

$file = $_GET['url'];

$imageNewName = "david_".basename($file);

//echo $imageNewName;

//download image

download($file,2000);

/*
Set Headers
Get total size of file
Then loop through the total size incrementing a chunck size
*/

function download($file,$chunks){
    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    //header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
      header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$imageNewName");
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    $size = get_size($file);
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);

    $i = 0;
    while($i<=$size){
        //Output the chunk
        get_chunk($file,(($i==0)?$i:$i+1),((($i+$chunks)>$size)?$size:$i+$chunks));
        $i = ($i+$chunks);
    }    
}

//Callback function for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, This is what prints the chunk
function chunk($ch, $str) {
    print($str);
    return strlen($str);
}

//Function to get a range of bytes from the remote file
function get_chunk($file,$start,$end){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, $start.'-'.$end);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'chunk');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

//Get total size of file
function get_size($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    return intval($size);
}
?>
```

Comment: You're opening the string with a single quote and closing it with a double quote...

Comment: There is an error in your code. It should be visible when you open the file. If it is not then you need to configure PHP to show errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write this line as follows:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$imageNewName);
```

Therefore, the string is closed and $imageNewName is concatenated to it.

Comment: i tried this the image start downloading but with the name of script that i call is used for new image name! The name of imaged to be saved becomes script.php but i want it the name of image to be whatever is in $imageNewName!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: thanks i had to pass $imageNewName variable to the function that is why your solution was not working!

Comment: Haha, that kind of stuff happens :P